# Keep Test classes in sync with Source classes

Tags: eclipse, junit, tdd, automated-refactoring

In Eclipse, I have two source folders, one called `src` the other called `test`. They have the exact same package structure and each src Class has a test equivalent with "Test" appended to its name. Sometimes, I move my src classes during refactoring. Is there a setting where Eclipse automatically moves the test classes as well? Also, the same with renaming source classes.

Answer (score 1):

No, because eclipse doesn't know the convention you are writing about.

Comment: is there a convention it knows about?

Comment: @bizso09: Not for this use case. Your only chance is to find a [plug-in](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/) or develop one on your own.

Comment: This question is very old but apparently still relevant. Maybe by now there is a plugin or similar that can keep test classes in sync with source classes?